# Where can I find a package firm that does the same as Moo does, but for packaging?

Tags: packaging

I have a package design made. I can change that design based on the specific package format that company may have. However, I can't find any company online that produces this kind of services, and ships internationally.

Can I have your advice on this please?
Where can I look at?

Update - This specific package need, is for creating a box, to be shipped everywhere (so material must be resistent), and it will contain, wine bootles, cheese, and some other grossery stuff. 
So, we draw this very specific box, and we have no clue where can we make this draw, became an object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be a bit more specific as to the type of packaging you are asking about. There are many companies with international reach in the industry, but the answer would depend entirely on the nature of the packaging and product.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually contact a local printer for that kind of specific printing. You can also shop for general printing online; **any offset printer will be happy to find a supplier for you** if they cannot print the boxes themselves. They will act as intermediary in that case. They will do any kind of custom box for you.

Another option if you absolutely want to shop online is to have a look at alibaba.com. It's another place where you can find all kind of printers who do high quality box packaging and ship internationally. Most suppliers are in China though but the products (including special boxes and packaging) are very high quality.

There's a lot of choice too and solid boxes as the ones you described; you can have a look at the website and browse the products OR you can select a few suppliers and ask for quotes for custom made packages since you already have your design.

If you decide to choose another style of box for any reason, you can ask them to provide the dieline and use it to have the perfect dimensions of your box for your design. You might need to order your boxes first though.

Note that if what you're looking for is some kind of "drop ship" service (someone who mail your items for you), then you'll probably need to get your boxes printed, and then find a company specialized in distribution.